# Online mp3 audio player

Tags: jquery, mp3, media-player

Does anyone know if there is a script for an mp3 player like that(in the picture section)? so minimal..

http://www.svenweisemann.com/index.php

Comment: You can use the HTML5 [audio](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_audio.asp) tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The center of the page is using the [jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org/) jquery pluggin and mp3s/ogas hosted on that website.

There are a bunch of demos on the jPlayer website you can play around with if you want to make your own player:
http://www.jplayer.org/latest/demos/

In the lower right hand corner, that website you post is using [soundcloud.com](http://soundcloud.com) to host its mp3s.

Here is a discussion for how to embed the soundcloud widget on your website here: http://soundcloud.com/pages/widgets

Comment: it is not soundcloud. I mean the player up, not the emdedded one that is down.

Comment: and I guess he did a custom css styling?

Comment: Yeah, you can read his code (it's very clean), but you should ask him before making anything derivative...

Answer (score 1):

I don't even know why i answered on this question...

**Tut:** http://www.codebasehero.com/2011/06/html-music-player/

### **DEMO:** http://www.codebasehero.com/files/music-player/demo/

CHECKOUT html5 audio 'players'

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_sounds.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_soundmidiembed

Answer (score 0):

Use The below code.
And change " [Mp3Plus.IN](http://mp3plus.in) or http://mp3plus.in" the url with your mp3 link

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>My Example</title>

<audio src="http://mp3plus.in .mp3" controls> 
<p>Fallback content goes here.</p>
</audio>
```